# Perl check if filename matching a pattern exists recursively

Tags: perl

I'm looping through folders in a directory and need to check if a file that matches a pattern exists in each directory. I've used glob but it seems to work for the the first folder only. I get file not found for the second folder even I know that it's there.
Here is my code:

```
my @dirs = grep { -d } glob '/data/test_all_runs/*';

for my $dir ( @dirs ) {

    print "the directory is $dir\n";
    my $run_folder = (split '/', $dir)[3];
    print "the folder is $run_folder\n";

    my $matrix_excel =  $dir."/*bcmatrix.xls";
    my $summary_excel = $dir."/*bc_summary.xls";

    unless (-e $summary_excel) {
   if (glob($summary_excel)) {
             At least one file matches "*.file"
            }
            else
            {
        print "File Doesn't Exist!";
        print STDERR "|=============================================|\n";
        print STDERR "|                                             |\n";
        print STDERR "|       Can't find Summary .xls File!!!       |\n";
        print STDERR "|                                             |\n";
        print STDERR "|   Upload the file and rerun the program.    |\n";
        print STDERR "|                                             |\n";
        print STDERR "|=============================================|\n";

                die;
    }
  }
```

Is there another method to check if `*bcmatrix.xls` file exists in each folder of `/data/test_all_runs/*`?

Comment: `glob ( "/data/test_all_runs/*/*bcmatrix.xls")`?

Comment: Do you really need a script for this when `grep` will do?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Your code defines glob patterns `$matrix_excel` and `$summary_excel`, and then checks for files matching `$summary_excel` (unless a file with a name *equal to* the pattern exists, for some reason). But then you ask about `*bcmatrix.xls` in your text. Which one are you looking for? Are you looking for a *pair* that matches both glob patterns with the same prefix? How do you expect to find files matching `$matrix_excel` if you never use that pattern? Don't you want a *list* of all matching files, rather than just a yes/no to say that they exist?

Comment: I'm looking for both $matrix_excel and $summary_excel but only included one of them in the code example. `*bcmtrix.xls` is looking for the $matrix_excel. I only want to find out if $matrix_excel and $summary_excel exist in each folder. If not the user needs to upload the files. and rerun the program. Thx

Comment: Please explain more precisely. It sounds like you're looking for exactly one `*bcmatrix.xls` and one `*bc_summary.xls` in every subdirectory of `/data/test_all_runs`, and those two files must have identical prefixes. Anything else is an error, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use something like this. It will build a hash of arrays that lists all the files in each subdirectory of `/data/test_all_runs` that look like either `*bcmatrix.xls` or `*bc_summary.xls`

You should be able to do what you want with the result

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Spec::Functions 'splitdir';

my %files;

for my $path ( glob '/data/test_all_runs/*/*{bcmatrix,bc_summary}.xls' ) {

    my ($subdir, $file) = (splitdir $path)[-2, -1];

    push @{ $files{$subdir} }, $file;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%files;
```

Comment: because the hash contains an array of values for each key it is more difficult to check if each file type exists once I fill the hash.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit overkill, but it seems to do what you need. I use [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) to fetch all of the directories in the directory structure, then use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) to get the list of file names that match the pattern:

Given this directory structure:

```
orig
  |-a
    |-a.txt
  |-b
    |-ba.txt
  |-c
```

With this code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Basename;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = 'orig';
my $file = 'a.txt';

my @dirs = File::Find::Rule->directory
                           ->in($dir);

for (@dirs){
    next if /(?:\.|\.\.)/;

    if (my @files = glob "$_/*$file"){
        for my $path (@files){
            my $name = basename $path;
            print "file $name exists in $_\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        print "file not found in directory $_\n";
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
file not found in directory orig
file ba.txt exists in orig/b
file not found in directory orig/c
file a.txt exists in orig/a
```

Comment: I don't see it as an overkill -- it also gives them full control over the process (along with the solution).